# Swift XCUITest: How to click on the default "Choose" button of UIImagePickerController() while performing the UI test?

Tags: swift, xcuitest

I am writing the UI test case, where I am supposed to select a picture from the gallery and display it on the ImageView that I have.
I am successfully able to write the UI test which clicks on ImageView, then selects the image, but unable to click on the "Choose" button.

Currently, I am using this code

```
        app.sheets["Profile Picture"].buttons["Open Photos"].tap()
        let selectedImage = app.images["Photo, March 31, 2018, 12:44 AM"]
        selectedImage.tap()
        app.buttons["Choose"].tap() // This is not working!!
```

My UI looks like this.[image]

Comment: What does your debugDescription show? Does the choose button .exist? I have seen cases where things like this are not hittable and coordinates must instead be tapped.

Comment: Hi @MikeCollins
Yes, the choose buttons exists.
XCTAssertTrue(app.buttons["Choose"].exists)  - This works fine.

Comment: Then I suspect Roman's answer below might solve your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Will `app.buttons["Choose"].tapUnhittable()` work?

```
    func tapUnhittable() {
        XCTContext.runActivity(named: "Tap \(self) by coordinate") { _ in
            coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)).tap()
        }
    }
```

Add this extension or import https://github.com/devexperts/screenobject

Answer (score 0):

For the use button, after you selected an image from the gallery

`app.buttons["Done"].tap()`

worked for me.